# How can I reduce the CPU usage of Offline Files?

Tags: windows-7, sync, offline-files

Whenever I have the Offline Files service running, there is a constant 25% CPU usage on svchost.exe (this is a quad core, so that means it's using up one core).

This, in turn, triples the power consumption and keeps the machine hot...

I *do* have several GB synchronized (music collection), but they are not changing at all, in either side.

Am I misusing this feature? Is there anything I can configure to keep it down when there's nothing to do?

Or should I forget about it and synchronize big folders manually?

Answer (score 2):

Even though the music files are not changed, some CPU cycles are used to check that they are not modified. I mean offline files checks timestamps of each and every file in the share..

It is usually suggested to offline only important documents.

Have you checked that it's the svchost that runs csc service. Svchost hosts lots of other services too.

http://offlinefiles.blogspot.com

Comment: The service is definitely csc: when I stop it usage goes down to 0. I couldn't find anything related to performance in that blog, although it looks useful.